# Как извлечь подстроку из строки

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Есть данные записанные в куки:

```
setcookie("cp_".$fname, $hash, time()+3600*24*3);
```

**$fname** - содержит в себе название файла сгенерированного с помощью **uniqid()** и записанного в базе и соответствующий ему **hash**. В куках по мимо этих записей содержатся записи не соответствующие шаблону "**cp_**" которые нужно исключить сразу.

Делаю перебор массива:

```
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value){
 /* обработка значений */
}
```

Но не могу представить как правильно отсечь данные в которых нет префикса "**cp_**", а в тех в которых есть его убрать получив **$fname**. В конце мне нужно получить либо нумерованный массив с **$fname** либо строку с каким-нибудь разделителем.

Подскажите, каким образом можно решить задачу?

Comment: Подсказываю. Вам нужны [if](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.if.php), [substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php) и [операторы сравнения](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: каким образом substr мне может помочь для исключения записей вообще не подходящих шаблону допустим тот же PHPSESSID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fname = array()
foreach (array_keys($_COOKIE) as $key) { 
    if (strpos($k,'cp_') === 0) {
        $fname[] = substr($k, 3);
    }
{
var_dump($fname);
```

думаю что как-то так

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_COOKIE as $k=>$v)
{
$pos = strpos($k,"cp_");
if ($pos !== false)
    {
    $fname = substr($k,$pos);
    print $fname."<br>";
    }
```

Как-то так. Если не работает,сделайте Print_r своего массива $_COOKIE и напишите здесь, исправлю.

..добавлено
ТС, еще раз повторюсь, сделайте print_r массива кук и выложите сюда.

Comment: 1cp_12  
вполне успешно пройдет проверку

Comment: cp_52c3ae028fa3f.png после обработки вернет строку cp_52c3ae028fa3f_png